# Indexing a smaller matrix into the center of a larger matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I am attempting the following as a hobby and not homework.  I am new to MATLAB with limited knowledge of coding in general.  I have a problem that I'm stuck on.  It's from *Computer Programming with MATLAB: J. Michael Fitzpatrick and Akos Ledeckzi*

Problem 10. Write a function called `cancel_middle` that takes **A**, an **n**-by-**m**
matrix, as an input where both **n** and **m** are odd numbers and **k**, a positive
odd integer that is smaller than both **m** and **n** (the function does not have to
check the input). The function returns the input matrix with its center **k** by **k** matrix zeroed out. Check out the following run,

```
>> cancel_middle(ones(5),3)
ans =
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have a nested if function that will properly execute the input arguments, but I can't get the desired output.  I believe it is far from efficient, and I am using if statements even though it has not been covered in the book.  That's from my previous knowledge.  So I think there's a much simpler, more efficient function to be written.

```
function M = cancel_middle(A,k);

[m,n] = size(A);
if rem([m,n],2) == [1,1]
    if rem(k,2)==1
        if [k,k]<[m,n]
            M = zeros(k);

        else
            fprintf('Error 1: k must be odd and smaller than A\n');
        end
    else
        fprintf('Error 2: k must be odd and smaller than A\n');
    end
else
    fprintf('Error 3: k must be odd and smaller than A\n');
end
```

The area I'm stuck on is the output argument that should be on line 8.  I'm outputting the k-by-k matrix correctly, but it's not on the larger matrix for obvious reasons.  I believe I want take the matrix `zeros(k)` and index it onto the larger matrix, A.  I believe I'm missing some critical functions that will relieve me of using 3 if statements too, but I am very much in the dark on that.

Here is the output when I run my function:

```
>> cancel_middle(ones(5),3)
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

Clearly it's just the `zeros(k)` output.

Comment: Most of your code thus far seems to be doing checks of inputs (which your problem specifically doesn't ask for). Rather than create a separate matrix of zeroes, consider how to calculate the indices of which elements of A should become zero and set them directly...

Comment: @etmuse I am running those checks so the function can determine if the inputs are indeed what the question asks for.  So if I entered a matrix of size 4-by-4, I would get an error as intended.  I do like your approach of changing the specified elements of A to zero instead of creating a separate zeros matrix.  Thank you

Comment: I would suggest giving [this](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html) a read to familiarize yourself with indexing, as that will be key to solving this kind of problem.

Comment: @SardarUsama, yep! definitely a strong duplicate. This assignment must be recurring ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you already covered the *indexing* parts of MATLAB but if not I strongly advise to read up about them because that is one of the pilar of the strength of MATLAB:

- [Array Indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html)
- [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Once this is understood, the exercise is to calculate which indices of your matrix will be zeroed. Once you have the list of indices, assiging a value to the elements of a matrix positioned at these location is a one line trivial assignment.

Consider the following function below (excuse the verbose and long variable names but I tried to make it didactic). The result values given in comments at the end of each line are valid for an example set of input `A=ones(5,7)` and `k=3`:

```
function M = cancel_middle(A,k)

    % find [m,n] (the size of A)
    [m,n] = size(A) ; % => m=5, n=7

    % calculate the coordinates of the "center" of the matrix
    center_row_idx = (m+1)/2  ; % => center_row_idx = 3
    center_col_idx = (n+1)/2  ; % => center_col_idx = 4

    % how much indices to take on each side of the center
    half_width = (k-1)/2 ;      % => center_row_idx = 3

    % generate the indices which will be zeroed
    row_indices = center_row_idx-half_width:center_row_idx+half_width ; % => row_indices = [2,3,4]
    col_indices = center_col_idx-half_width:center_col_idx+half_width ; % => col_indices = [3,4,5]

    % generate the output matrix M (as a copy of A)
    M = A ;
    % now you can zero the elements of matrix M directly by their indices
    M(row_indices,col_indices) = 0 ;

end
```

You can verify:

```
>> M = cancel_middle(ones(5,7),3)
M =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexed assignment with [`end`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) as follows:

```
A = randi(9,5,7); % example A
k = 3; % example k
t = -(k-1)/2:(k-1)/2;
A((end+1)/2 + t, (end+1)/2 + t) = 0;
```

Example result:

```
A =
     2     5     2     9     3     6     9
     6     3     0     0     0     4     8
     7     7     0     0     0     8     5
     6     2     0     0     0     5     6
     5     7     1     5     8     4     6
```

Comment: The code golf has rubbed too much on you Luis :-) But +1 anyway for a nice trick with the `end` keyword.

Comment: @Hoki Nah. A golfed version would be `t=1-k/2:k/2;A(end/2+t,end/2+t)=0` :-)